# Targeting playbook hosts depending on host variable value

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an Ansible inventory `inventory.ini` structured as follows (shortened for the example):

```ini
[prod:children]
prod_first_plateform

[prod_first_plateform:children]
database_prod_first_plateform
embedded_prod_first_plateform
ldap_prod_first_plateform
proxy_prod_first_plateform

[database_prod_first_plateform]
serverA team=developer
serverZ team=integrator

[embedded_prod_first_plateform]
serverB team=integrator
serverY team=integrator

[ldap_prod_first_plateform]
serverC team=developer
serverX team=integrator

[proxy_prod_first_plateform]
serverD team=developer
serverW team=developer
```

The requirement is as follows:

I would like to use this inventory in different contexts:

- To target all of my servers (with `hosts: all`)
- To target a specific platform (with `hosts: prod_first_plateform`, in this example)
- To target machines belonging to a specific team (depending on the `team` host variable, while adhering to this inventory syntax, without adding a new host group.

My issue lies with this third point.

My idea would be to use a syntax which works in my playbook like `hosts: all[team=developer]`.
I know this syntax doesn't work, but I try to found a correct way to achieve that.

Is this currently possible with this inventory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`group_by`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/group_by_module.html) module in a preliminary play in order to create yourself groups from a variable.

Given:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - group_by:
        key: "hosts_of_team_{{ team }}"
      when: team is defined

- hosts: hosts_of_team_developer
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts
      run_once: true
```

Running it on your inventory, the second play would yield:

```yaml
ok: [serverA] => 
  ansible_play_hosts:
  - serverA
  - serverC
  - serverD
  - serverW
```

As expected, since we are targeting the hosts where the variable `team` equal `developer` via `hosts: hosts_of_team_developer`.